# TFS2015: gated check-in build locking files

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm trying to setup a gated check-in build (vNext) on a TFS2015.3 server.
After I check-in a modification the build is triggered. The build runs smooth but the modified files are remaining locked by Project Collection Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION).

From the build logs I can see that the "Check in gated changes" step is performed correctly.

If the team project source control has the multiple check-out option disable I'm not able to modify the locked files unless I unlock them or we queue the build again.

Any idea how to determine the gated check-in build to unlock the files at the end?

**Update**

After more tests I've found that the gated check-in build is releasing the files on a newly created collection; the locking issue is happening on a collection upgraded from TFS2012.

**Update 2**

Manually running again (after a gated check-in) the build cause the files to be unlocked:

> Undo any pending changes under workspace.
>
> tf undo Undoing edit:
>
> D:\B\2\3\s\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 0929**

> @danielstefanescu - looks like it was fixed yesterday. Should be in
>   next update (2.107.1)
>
> *bryanmacfarlane commented*
>
> **Related issue**:[tf undo at end of a shelveset/gated build #588](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/588#issuecomment-250178501)

---

This phenomenon also [occurs with some others](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fbf47430-471b-48b6-a67e-bc060f88681f/tfs-2015-update-2-gated-checkins?forum=tfsbuild). However, test in my environment, works pretty well with the collection created by TFS 2015 (don't have the collection upgraded from TFS 2012).

According to the link above, seems close Visual Studio and  come back a bit later the files no longer show checked out. However, after checking in more changes and the next gated check-in succeeded but now the files still show checked out again by "***Project Collection Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION)***". You can also give a try with your side.

This is very likely a BUG. And I have key one in Microsoft connect site. You can  follow the action of it and also share the information if you have found some more useful trouble shootings.

> **Gated check-in build still locking files even after the build
>   finished**
>   https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3100862

Comment: Looks like this issue will be fixed in next update. Source Link: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/588#issuecomment-250178501

Answer (score 0):

I had this same this issue.

Steps to Fix:

1. Log into TFS Server with the same account the TFS service is running.
2. Open Visual Studio. I had 2013 which does not require a license.
3. Go to Team Explorer.
4. Connect to Source Control Explorer.
5. Go to the files that are locked, right click and undo pending changes.

You may need to change to the correct workspace if option is disabled.