# TFS 2017 XAML Build Locking Files

Tags: tfsbuild

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259327/tfs2015-gated-check-in-build-locking-files), except we are not using gated check-in.  We were on TFS 2013 Update 4, and recently upgraded to 2017 Update 1.  Our XAML builds will run once successfully after a service restart, and then fail with permission denied errors.  When I check the server, it is because the NUnit files are locked by the build service.

Has anyone been able to get past this without moving to vNext?

Comment: Where are you XAML builds running? You cannot install a standalone TFS 2017 XAML build server so either you have installed XAML build on your application tier or you are using a TFS 2013 XAML build standalone server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TfsBuildServiceHost.exe` holds a handle to the NUnit test adapter assemblies.  And then will get an Exception Message: `Access to the path '<assemblyfilepath>' is denied`.  Seems to be a bug.Take a look at this similar issue:[TFSBuildServiceHost maintains a lock on assemblies, TFS 2015](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41ea0c49-1600-4348-968a-146b2392a335/tfsbuildservicehost-maintains-a-lock-on-assemblies-tfs-2015?forum=tfsbuild)  You could submit a Bug in this new place [Develop Community-Team Foundation Server](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/22/index.html) and will get quick response by develop team.

---

Moreover, XAML Build are deprecated in TFS 2017 and will not be available in tge next version of TFS. VSTS already no longer supports them.

> **I'm looking for the hosted XAML build controller. Where did it go?**
>
> The hosted XAML build controller is no longer supported. Accounts
>   created on or after April 2016 do not have access to it. We plan to
>   remove the hosted XAML build controller from all accounts, possibly as
>   soon as March 2017.
>
> [Source](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted)

Highly recommend you to convert your builds to vNext Build to access some new technology and support. For more please refer [Why Should I Leave XAML Builds?](http://blog.devmatter.com/why-should-i-leave-xaml-builds/)

Comment: Yes, that's the error.  At least it's not just me.  We had planned on moving to the new build processes, but as time permitted as opposed to right away.  I have spent the last two days converting builds and PowerShell scripts, but have hopes the process will go faster now that I have a proper feel for the process.